# QGIS file went missing?

Tags: qgis, memory

I was working on a file for a few weeks, saving it on an external drive, in a folder, along with all layers and shapefiles. Today I went to open it and the file is gone. Not in recycle bin or anywhere that I can find. The associated layers are still there. Any idea what could've happened? Luckily this was for school and I've exported most of what I needed into Illustrator, but I'd like to go back in and tweak a few things.

If I got to "open recent", I can see the path of where it was, but it has a little exclamation in a triangle, which I assume means it cannot locate the file.

Comment: Deleted by accident? Removed to another folder? It's dificult to do more than guesswork.

Comment: I thought so but haven't been able to locate it searching the recycle bin or other folders. Luckily I have a backup from last night on backblaze but I just wondered if this was a certain issue with QGIS (semi new to it, here), or something on my end. I assume the latter.